# AttributeError: 'OAuthRemoteApp' object has no attribute 'authorized_response'

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, oauth, flask

I'm trying to authorize my application with twitter login authentication but after login into Twitter, It is not redirecting into my main page. It shows error:

**[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJou6.png)**

Here is my source code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import g, session, request, url_for, flash
from flask import redirect, render_template
from flask_oauth import OAuth


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'

oauth = OAuth()

# Use Twitter as example remote application
twitter = oauth.remote_app('twitter',
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/',    
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',    
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',    
    consumer_key='xxxxxxx',
    consumer_secret='xxxxxxx'
)


@twitter.tokengetter
def get_twitter_token():
    if 'twitter_oauth' in session:
        resp = session['twitter_oauth']
        return resp['oauth_token'], resp['oauth_token_secret']


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None
    if 'twitter_oauth' in session:
        g.user = session['twitter_oauth']


@app.route('/')
def index():
    tweets = None
    if g.user is not None:
        resp = twitter.request('statuses/home_timeline.json')
        if resp.status == 200:
            tweets = resp.data
        else:
            flash('Unable to load tweets from Twitter.')
    return render_template('index.html', tweets=tweets)


@app.route('/tweet', methods=['POST'])
def tweet():
    if g.user is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
    status = request.form['tweet']
    if not status:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    resp = twitter.post('statuses/update.json', data={
        'status': status
    })
    if resp.status == 403:
        flash('Your tweet was too long.')
    elif resp.status == 401:
        flash('Authorization error with Twitter.')
    else:
        flash('Successfully tweeted your tweet (ID: #%s)' % resp.data['id'])
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback_url = url_for('oauthorized', next=request.args.get('next'))
    return twitter.authorize(callback=callback_url or request.referrer or None)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('twitter_oauth', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/oauthorized')
def oauthorized():

    resp = twitter.authorized_response()

    if resp is None:
        flash('You denied the request to sign in.')
    else:
        session['twitter_oauth'] = resp
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**PLEASE HELP ME...
ANY KIND OF HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!**

Comment: Comparing your login function with the example in the Flash documentation, yours is different. See https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/ maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

in your `oauthorized` function remove `resp = twitter.authorized_response()` statement and add a `resp` parameter to the function. it would be something like this:

```
@app.route('/oauthorized')
@twitter.authorized_response
def oauthorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        flash('You denied the request to sign in.')
    else:
        session['twitter_oauth'] = resp
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Additionally, you need to decorate the function with `@twitter.authorized_handler` in order for it to accept the `resp` argument. I've updated the example.